# HP-Health (hpasmcli) problem

Tags: hp

I have a "ProLiant DL360p Gen8" server with iLO version 2.54.

If I run "hpasmcli" it won't open the cli but gives the following error:

```
$ hpasmcli 
ERROR: Could not open /dev/cpqhealth/cdt.
Please make sure the Health Monitor is started.
```

hp-health Check:

```
$ systemctl status hp-health
● hp-health.service - HP System Health Monitor
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/hp-health.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Do 2017-09-21 16:40:36 CEST; 12min ago
```

hp-health log is not showing any useful information. Only displaying "hp-health" started correct.

Does anyone has an idea or the same problem? On all other server the "hpasmcli" is running correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found my own solution.
For everyone looking at the same issue my solution was to install the package "mcelog".

It is described here: https://community.hpe.com/t5/Insight-Control-for-Linux/CentOS-6-2-hp-health-fail/td-p/5431885

Comment of: Naresh_Kumar
Time: ‎08-21-2012 09:12 AM
Point: 1

This Daemon was not necessary on RHEL 7 but the package is. The "hp-health" package has no dependency to this package...

Answer (score 0):

FWIW

```
systemctl restart hp-health
```

solved it here.

Answer (score -1):

Reboot your ILO. You can do this with `hponcfg -b`.

Usually you can restart the `hp-snmp-agents` service to restore this, but it's possible that the ILO is in a weird state.

Can you connect to the ILO's web interface?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this didn't solved the problem.
I rebooted the server too but no success.
Any other idea?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7

Comment: Not true service is not installed.